# Could not connect galaxy s3 i9300 using smart switch & Samsung kies after rooting

Tags: windows-7, android, galaxy-s3, kies

I have done a backup of my galaxy s3 4.3 using smart switch so i can recover my data after doing an update to 5.1.1 of android version.

After the update i was not been able to connect via smart switch and it tell me "unsupported device"

[image]

Also when trying to use samsung kies the connection can't be established.

[image]
However, device drivers of the phone are correctly installed and i can access my phone directly from the computer (windows 7 64-bits).

Any suggestions ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't work due to the bootloader. Try [Krazyroot](http://krazyroot.com/) first. Then install SuperSU from the Play Store, and let it uninstall Knox.